# Get all the logs since 5 days

Tags: mongodb

The logs in my database is like `{..., "date" : ISODate("2021-09-09T23:05:00.738Z"), ...}`

I have the following code to get the logs since the second of September:

```
db.getCollection('logs')
.find({
   "date":{"$gt":ISODate("2021-09-02")}
})
.sort({date:-1})
```

Does anyone know how to get all the logs since 5 days? I tried queries with `Date.now()`, but did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with this condition :

- To use dates in your queries, you need to wrap the strings in ISODate
- Dates need to be in Y-M-D format I’m guessing you probably want to
  also include data from the last day of April. In this case you should
  bring the end date forward by one day.

```js
{date:{$gte:ISODate("2021-09-05"),$lt:ISODate("2020-09-10"}}
```

Different Way:

5_DAYS = 4.32e+8;

```js
find({date : {$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 5_DAYS) } } )
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to use fixed dates like `2021-09-05`, I always want the last 5 days...

Comment: Try with this timestamp condition @SoftTimur find({timestamp : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 1xxxx) } } )

Comment: @SoftTimur keep in mind that the answer Hai Thai provided in the comment will help you find exactly what you asked for "Last 5 24 hr periods", assuming you make the "60*60*1000" what you want. This means it will 'find' starting from the same time of the day 5 days ago, not the beginning of that day. If you want it to include the whole day 5 days ago, then you can use what he provided in his answer and calculate the YYYY-mm-dd for the $lt:ISODate part or you can adjust the new Date() to this upcoming midnight

Comment: They don't work for me. For instance, `db.getCollection('logs').find({timestamp : {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime()-1000*60*1000)}})` returns 0 record. Probably because I don't have `timestamp` in the log?

Comment: Sorry my bad, use `date` instead of `timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Us the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({date: {$gt: moment().startOf('day').subtract(5, 'days').toDate()} } )
```

Comment: Is it possible to load moment.js in Robo 3T?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW) and [`$dateAdd`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$gt": [ "$date", { $dateAdd: { startDate: "$$NOW", unit: "day", amount: -5 } } ]
      },
      {
        "$lte": [ "$date", "$$NOW" ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zBtwdvKQ_gv)